# How to edit Invoice sending to email after success from paypal in oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

I am trying to find the invoice which sends to user on success from paypal in oscommerce. I found invoice.php which is under the admin folder. I want to add a field in the invoice which is sending to the user but didnot found the desired file

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple email is sending through checkout_process.php file. Search for tep_mail which will be on line 257 or nearby.